# Simple MSAL Login/Authentication in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm trying to do a simple login to Azure AD using the MSAL for JavaScript v2.0 library. We want users to be able to authenticate into our site with their work Microsoft accounts. All I need to do is be able to authenticate/login the user via Microsoft, and if they can login via their work Microsoft account, then they're granted access to our site.

I'm using the Javascript library and have followed the code from the [Github page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser) and while the login prompt is coming up, afterwards I have no idea how to check if the user is signed in.

Here's the code I'm using, which is basically what's in the sample code from Github:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.15.0/js/msal-browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const msalConfig = {
            auth: {
                clientId: "[ClientID goes here]",
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant ID]",
                knownAuthorities: ["login.microsoftonline.com"],
                protocolMode: "OIDC",
                redirectUri: "[page on our site that doesn't have MSAL auth, listed in Azure Reply URLs]"
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
                storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
            },
            system: {
                loggerOptions: {
                    loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
                        if (containsPii) {
                            return;
                        }
                        switch (level) {
                            case msal.LogLevel.Error:
                                console.error(message);
                                return;
                            case msal.LogLevel.Info:
                                console.info(message);
                                return;
                            case msal.LogLevel.Verbose:
                                console.debug(message);
                                return;
                            case msal.LogLevel.Warning:
                                console.warn(message);
                                return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // Add here scopes for id token to be used at MS Identity Platform endpoints.
        const loginRequest = {
            scopes: ["User.Read"]
        };

        const silentRequest = {
            scopes: ["openid", "profile", "User.Read"]
        };

        const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        const msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        const msie11 = ua.indexOf("Trident/");
        const msedge = ua.indexOf("Edge/");
        const isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
        const isEdge = msedge > 0;

        let signInType;
        let accountId = "";
        let credType = "";

        // Create the main myMSALObj instance
        const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

        // Register Callbacks for Redirect flow
        myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise().then(handleResponse).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });

        function handleResponse(resp) {
            alert("beginning handleResponse");

            if (resp !== null) {
                accountId = resp.account.homeAccountId;
                credType = resp.account.credentialType;

                myMSALObj.setActiveAccount(resp.account);

                alert("response not null (already auth), accountId: " + accountId + ", credType: " + credType);
            }
            else {
                const currentAccounts = myMSALObj.getAllAccounts();

                if (!currentAccounts || currentAccounts.length < 1) {
                    alert("currentAccounts null/empty, going to signIn");

                    signIn("loginRedirect");

                    //return;
                }
                else if (currentAccounts.length > 1) {
                    // add choose account code here
                    alert("currentAccounts has multiple");
                }
                else if (currentAccounts.length === 1) {
                    const activeAccount = currentAccounts[0];

                    myMSALObj.setActiveAccount(activeAccount);

                    accountId = activeAccount.homeAccountId;
                    credType = activeAccount.credentialType;

                    alert("currentAccounts == 1; accountId: " + accountId + ", credType: " + credType);
                }
            }
        }

        async function signIn(method) {
            signInType = isIE ? "loginRedirect" : method;
            if (signInType === "loginPopup") {
                return myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest).then(handleResponse).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
            else if (signInType === "loginRedirect") {
                return myMSALObj.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
            }
        }

        function signOut() {
            const logoutRequest = {
                account: myMSALObj.getAccountByHomeId(accountId)
            };

            myMSALObj.logoutRedirect(logoutRequest);
        }

        async function getTokenPopup(request, account) {
            request.account = account;

            return await myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request).catch(async (error) => {
                console.log("silent token acquisition fails.");

                if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                    console.log("acquiring token using popup");

                    return myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(request).catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });
        }

        // This function can be removed if you do not need to support IE
        async function getTokenRedirect(request, account) {
            request.account = account;

            return await myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(request).catch(async (error) => {
                console.log("silent token acquisition fails.");

                if (error instanceof msal.InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                    // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
                    console.log("acquiring token using redirect");

                    myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(request);
                }
                else {
                    console.error(error);
                }
            });
        }
```

So what happens upon going to this page is I get the two alerts saying "beginning handleResponse" and then "currentAccounts null/empty, going to signIn."

Then I'm redirected to MS sign-in page which I do with my work MS account. This succeeds.

I'm then redirected to the site I have listed in Azure Reply URLs, another page on our site that isn't secure and has no Azure login code.

The problem is I have no idea where to check that the user is signed in. If I try and check immediately after the `signIn("loginRedirect")` call in the `handleResponse()` function on the first page, the code never gets hit apparently. If I try and check on the page I'm redirected to, by instantiating the MSAL object and calling `getAllAccounts()`, this returns null.

It seems maybe on the page I'm redirected to I could call the `ssoSilent()` function (seems like this can check if user is authenicated?), but this requires a username/AccountId parameter. Well I don't frickin know this if a user hasn't (possibly) been authenticated yet! I don't really understand that.

So I don't know. It's probably something stupid I'm doing but I'm a pretty basic JavaScript person and am pretty much a total noob with authenication stuff. Any help would be epic.

Comment: One comment: you do not need to set protocolMode if you are using AAD as your authority.

Comment: Thanks! I'm super new to this sorta thing so any help is appreciated

Comment: I think I'm seeing issues because this library, or example code more specifically, is for Single Page Applications, which the website I'm working on IS NOT. It's just a regular website with multiple pages, no AJAX being used to switch out content elements. I noticed in the cookies sent back after successful authentication, the "status" cookie has a value of something akin to "in process" (that's not the value, but it seemed to kind of mean that). Just a guess though.